# How to change image src on mouseover and mouseleave in angular4 or above version?

Tags: angular6

I am very new to angular and I want to change src value using mouse over events. How we can do it in angular 4 or above version? Please help me.

```
export const ROUTES: RouteInfo[] = [
{ path: '/dashboard', title: 'Dashboard',  icon: 'fa fa-tachometer', class: '' ,name:'',src:"../../../../assets/images/header-icon.png",srcOn:"../../../../assets/images/dashboard_highlighted.png"},
{ path: '/forms', title: 'Forms',  icon:'fa fa-eyedropper', class: '',name:'',src:"../../../../assets/images/dashboard_highlighted.png",srcOn:""},
{ path: '/tables', title: 'Desk Blotter',  icon:'fa fa-pencil', class: '' ,name:'',src:"../../../../assets/images/dashboard_highlighted.png",srcOn:""},
{ path: '/bs-element', title: 'Admin',  icon:'fa fa-picture-o', class: '' ,name:'',src:"../../../../assets/images/dashboard_highlighted.png",srcOn:""},
{ path: '/login', title: 'Logout',  icon:'fa fa-power-off', class: '',name:'',src:"../../../../assets/images/dashboard_highlighted.png",srcOn:"" },
];

<li *ngFor="let menuItem of menuItems" routerLinkActive="active" class="{{menuItem.class}}" >
        <a [routerLink]="[menuItem.path]" name="{{menuItem.name}}">
           <img src="{{menuItem.src}}" style="width:66%;"  (mouseenter)="'src=''{{menuItem.srcOn}}'"   id="{{menuItem.title}}"/> {{menuItem.title}}
        </a>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let's look at this to see how to work with a model instead of rewriting element properties:

```
<img [src]="imgSrc"
           (mouseover)="imgSrc = 'http://www.impresabaraldo.it/Blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/casa-ecologica-vicenza.jpg'"
           (mouseout)="imgSrc = 'https://www.ediltecnico.it/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/casa-300x223.png'">
```

A possibile solution to your problem could be something like this:

```
export const ROUTES: RouteInfo[] = [
  { path: '/dashboard', title: 'Dashboard',  icon: 'fa fa-tachometer', class: '' ,name:'',src: '', srcOut: "../../../../assets/images/header-icon.png",srcOn:"../../../../assets/images/dashboard_highlighted.png"},
  { path: '/forms', title: 'Forms',  icon:'fa fa-eyedropper', class: '',name:'',src: '', srcOut: "../../../../assets/images/dashboard_highlighted.png",srcOn:""},
  { path: '/tables', title: 'Desk Blotter',  icon:'fa fa-pencil', class: '' ,name:'',src: '', srcOut: "../../../../assets/images/dashboard_highlighted.png",srcOn:""},
  { path: '/bs-element', title: 'Admin',  icon:'fa fa-picture-o', class: '' ,name:'',src: '', srcOut: "../../../../assets/images/dashboard_highlighted.png",srcOn:""},
  { path: '/login', title: 'Logout',  icon:'fa fa-power-off', class: '',name:'',src: '', srcOut: "../../../../assets/images/dashboard_highlighted.png",srcOn:"" },
];
```

Note that we have a src property and a srcOn and a srcOut. The idea is to bind images src property to this json object src property, then updating json object src property according to your mouse events

```
<li *ngFor="let menuItem of menuItems" routerLinkActive="active" class="{{menuItem.class}}" >
    <a [routerLink]="[menuItem.path]" name="{{menuItem.name}}">
      <img style="width:66%;"  id="{{menuItem.title}}"
           [src]="menuItem.src || menuItem.srcOut"
           (mouseover)="menuItem.src = menuItem.srcOn"
           (mouseout)="menuItem.src = menuItem.srcOut"/> {{menuItem.title}}
    </a>
  </li>
```

Finally I suggest you to use mouseover instead of mouseenter

Comment: <li *ngFor="let menuItem of menuItems" routerLinkActive="active" class="{{menuItem.class}}" >
            <a [routerLink]="[menuItem.path]" name="{{menuItem.name}}">
               <img [src]="imgSrc" style="width:66%;" (mouseover)="imgSrc ={{menuItem.srcOn}}"
                   (mouseout)="imgSrc = {{menuItem.src}}"
               /> {{menuItem.title}}
            </a>
        </li>

Comment: Getting Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 9 in [imgSrc ='{{menuItem.srcOn}}']

Comment: mine is an example. what I'm trying to say is that is convenient working with models, instead of trying to rewrite html elements. So don't try to add a src attribute in mouseover or mouseout. Instead try to bind your images src to a model, then update that model value

Comment: Could you please show me sample code of how can we bind them?